# Plone 4 - Get url of a file in a plone.app.blob.field.FileField

Tags: blob, plone, filefield

I have a custom content type with 3 FileFields (plone.app.blob.field.FileField) and I want to get their url's, so i can put them on my custom view and people will be able to download these files. 
However, when using Clouseau to test and debug, I call :

```
context.getFirst_file().absolute_url()
```

Where getFirst_file() is the accessor to the first file (field called 'first_file').

The url returned is 'http://foo/.../eat.00001', where 'eat.00001' is the object of my custom type that contains the file fields...

The interesting thing is, if I call:

```
context.getFirst_file().getContentType()
```

It returns 'application/pdf', which is correct since it's a pdf file.

I'm pretty lost here, any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File fields do not support a `absolute_url` method; instead, through [acquisition](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/Acquisition.html) you inherit the method from the object itself, hence the results you see. Moreover, calling `getFirst_field()` will return the actual downloadable contents of the field, not the field itself which could provide such information.

Instead, you should use the `at_download` script appended to the object URL, followed by the field id:

```
<a href="" tal:attributes="href string:${context/absolute_url}/at_download/first_file">First File</a>
```

You can also re-use the Archetypes widget for the field, by passing the field name to the `widget` method:

```
<metal:field use-macro="python:context.widget('first_field', mode='view')">
  First File
</metal:field>
```

This will display the file size, icon (if available), the filename and the file mime type.

In both these examples, I assumed the name of the field is 'first_field'.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Martijin!
With your help I managed to do what I wanted! :)

Comment: Glad I could help! Would you mind marking the answer as accepted? It's the V-shaped icon next to the answer voting score. :-)

Comment: About the second part of your answer: re-use archetypes widget. Is there a way to use an specific macro/widget to display objects content?

For example, I have some items in my object that are referenced using relatedItems. In the custom view, I would like to get each of these items (tal:repeat) and show it using a file widget. Is there a way to do it in a similar way of your example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually the issue is a little bit more complex.
The relatedItems are shown inside the 'content-core' slot. I would like to use this slot but show the relatedItems my own way "hiding" their default view from content-core slot.
I don't know if it is possible, any references or ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: The answer to that would not fit into a comment here; you are no longer displaying a "local" field, but a related content object. You could reuse the file widget macros but that'd require a lot more TAL and Archetypes foo.